# Animated Lines With Arrows Beetween Two Coordinates Google Maps Javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, google-maps-api-3, jquery-animate

I want to draw on google maps api v3 some lines going out of some center marker that the mouse is over at. For Example I'm moving mouse at the Berlin City Marker, some data is fetched in the bacground by ajax and I have 5 coordinates in response. I want to draw lines with arrows from this city (Berlin) to this 5 coordinates but drawing should be animated from berlin to those points.

This should be visible like the lines with those arrows are flying from Berlin to this 5 coordinates. Does anyone know how to do this animation in javascript. This should be work in PC browsers and mobile browsers. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom google maps overlay and on that layer place a canvas and incrementally draw the line to give it animation.